# EIP getting changed in fgetc() Buffer Overflow Homework

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, exploit-development

Here is the gist of the code:

```
main(){
  char s1[64], s2[64];
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  FILE *fp1, fp2*;
  char temp;
  scanf("%s", s1);
  scanf("%s", s2);
  ...
  //some checks happen, fp1 is opened to s1, fp2 is opened to s2,
  temp = fgetc(fp1);
  while(temp != EOF) {
    fputc(temp, fp2);
    temp = fgetc(fp1);
  }
  ...
}
```

In the first scanf I can overwrite the saved EIP and everything is fine until I step through that middle section. When the first (I'm using an empty file for s1 so it's also the only time it runs) `fgetc` returns the memory where the saved **EIP** is has been changed from 0x-------- to 0xff------. When I step through it it seems to happen in `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`

As this is homework hints are strongly preferred but if you want to see the whole `c`, `binary`, or `asm` [here's the link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jj83t77geqcaj1w/AADemQoUudjSeGgFqJscIj3ya?dl=0).

Comment: We really appreciate it when people specify that it's homework. Thanks!